# Problem with events (delegates) and inheritance in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have class `Base` which the has `event and delegate`. It is a base class for class `Button`. Also, I have class `Receiving`, inside this class I subscribe to event which is inside the class `Base`. For some reason this throws an error on the line where I call the event.

Class Base:

```cs
public class Base : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void SendSave(string root);
    public event SendSave sendSave;

    public Text _text;

    private string _saveName;

    public virtual void Tap()
    {
        MailingSave("Base");
    } 

    public void MailingSave(string name)
    {
        _saveName = name;
        sendSave(_saveName);
    }
}
```

Class Button

```
public class Button : Base
{ 
    public Text uiText;

    public override void Tap()
    {
        string _name = uiText.text;
        MailingSave(_name);
    }
}
```

Class Receiving

```
public class Receiving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Base _base;

    private void Start()
    {
       _base.sendSave += ToStringName;
    }

    private void ToStringName(string name)
   {
       Debug.Log(name);
   }

}
```

The error occurs in the `Base` class on the line `sendSave (_saveName);`.

Comment: Needs debugging details.

Comment: And what is the error? That will help us understand what is missing.

Comment: Are you sure, you have attached `Button` and `Receiving` scripts to some `GameObject`/s, and you are indeed calling `Tap` method of `Button` from somewhere in the code? Please make sure that the `m_Base.sendSave += ToStringName` gets called before you make a call to `Tap` method. Since there is no check, to see if `sendSave` is null or not, so `NullReferenceException` will get raised.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious compiler error in your code so without further details I can just guess you get a `NullReferenceException`.

This happens if the `sendSave` is invoked **before** anything is attached as a listener/callback.

You should **always** first check if there is any listener at all

```
if(sendSave != null)
{
    sendSave(_saveName);
}
```

which can also be written shorter as

```
sendSave?.Invoke(_saveName);
```

And then [debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and make sure that the line

```
_base.sendSave += ToStringName;
```

is actually invoked **at all** and **before** the event gets invoked!

e.g. is there a `Receiving` component in your scene at all and is it active and enabled?

---

**Update after your comments**

If you rather want this event to be globally fired and listened for **any** of the `Button` or other child classes then I would rather use a `static` event like

```
// Note that I would also make this static
// which automatically makes sure that only inherited components may be actually
// attached to an object but not this base class
public abstract class Base : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Additionally pass in which instance invoked this
    public delegate void SendSave(Base sender, string root);

    // Make this accessible static
    public static event SendSave sendSave;

    public Text _text;

    private string _saveName;

    public virtual void Tap()
    {
        MailingSave(nameof(Base));
    } 

    public void MailingSave(string name)
    {
        _saveName = name;

        sendSave?.Invoke(_saveName);
    }
}
```

And now you can attach your listener globally by simply using

```
public class Receiving : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
       Base.sendSave += ToStringName;
    }

    private void ToStringName(Base sender, string name)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Sender: \"{sender}\" saveName: \"{name}\"", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, My Problem was a `NullReferenceException` . But now I don't understand why the event subscription is not happening. The `Receiving` component is on scene and a line of code is being executed that subscribes the `Receiving` class method to the event.  But all the same, the event remains without subscribers.

Comment: @VladShpilMan are you sure you register to the correct instance of  `Base`/`Button` or whatever?

Comment: I have three buttons on the scene. Each button has a script `Button`. There are also two empties on which the `Receiving` and `Base`. I understand that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @VladShpilMan You most probably do not want the `Base` at all in your scene! You rather want to listen to the events of one of the `Button` components! Or if you want that to be globally listening to any button event then you might rather want to make the event `static`. See the update at the bottom of the answer